Need to repair sprinkler line
I chopped off a sprinkler head with my lawnmower. This was the last sprinkler in the line, so I’d love to replace it with another head, but I’m also ok with just plugging this and adjusting the other heads to cover this area. It seems to be an unpopular size of sprinkler line and I can’t find the right size plug or elbow for a new head. It probably came with the house when it was built in 2004.
The line seems to be a very hard rubber with a diameter of 3/4” on the outside and just over 1/4” on the inside.
Any suggestions for a fix here?

More likely black pipe/tubing and blue remains of the fitting that got chopped off.

You were absolutely right. I cut the line an inch over, and no more blue. This should be an easier fix now. Thank you!

Happy to help! Please [edit] to update your question so any answers are not barking up that tree in error.
